# ACPI Definition Block: Difference between _SB and _SB_ for System bus

Tags: linux-kernel, uefi, acpi, edk2

I'm investigating the edk2 (UEFI). So, I have some concerns about path of device defined in the DSDT table. In this table, we use `/_SB` for the root of system bus, but it's `/_SB_` on Linux. For instance, I checked via command

```
 $ cat /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM\:00/LNXSYBUS\:00/PNP0A08\:00/device\:00/path
```

And sometime, I also see some ACPI table use `/_SB_` for referring a device path.

Do you know how it is different? How use it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think so. The 4-bytes limitation only applies to the device name. And the length of a name is not mandatory in 4-bytes, it can be 2-byte or 3-bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACPI specification (I here and further refer to v6.4) [chapter 19.3.1](https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/19_ASL_Reference/ACPI_Source_Language_Reference.html#asl-names) defines characters allowed to be used in the names. Though it doesn't tell clearly what happened to the names shorter than 4 characters. This is clarified in [chapter 5.3](https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/05_ACPI_Software_Programming_Model/ACPI_Software_Programming_Model.html#acpi-namespace)

> By convention, when an ASL compiler pads a name shorter than 4 characters, it is done so with trailing underscores (‘_’). See the language definition for AML NameSeg in the ACPI Source Language (ASL) Reference chapter.

This is also confirmed by [chapter 20.4](https://uefi.org/htmlspecs/ACPI_Spec_6_4_html/20_AML_Specification/AML_Specification.html#aml-encoding-of-names-in-the-namespace) which shows byte stream in AML. In example the name

> \S2

is translated to

> RootChar 'S2__'

That said, the `\_SB` and `\_SB_` are the equivalent notations of the same name.